# How to fix “ImportError: cannot import name 'flags' ” while importing flags from config in Python

Tags: python

I am having a problem while playing the following code
https://github.com/zengguodong/iSeg_Bern_IPMI
The problem is on Line # 6 . When it plays it gives out an import error :

```
from config import FLAGS

ImportError: cannot import name 'FLAGS'
```

But when I install the 'FLAGS',it gives out that

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\zh>pip install FLAGS
Requirement already satisfied: FLAGS in d:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (0.0.1.2)
```

Comment: Edit your post to provide relevant code snippet inline. Nobody is going to follow your links to help you - they will get obsolete.

Comment: I believe that the code you are trying to run is incomplete...  There is a `config` package for python but it does not have the `FLAGS` property in it.  To make this code run you should create a `config.py` file in the same directory and add a `FLAGS` member.